# Get id of facebook user from email ASP

Tags: facebook, asp-classic

How would I get the userid of somebodys facebook from there email address :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an application and then use your access token with the following query:

`https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=EMAILADDRESS&type=user&access_token=ACCESSTOKEN`